# List of self-signed certificates on the server

Tags: debian, openssl, certificates

Is there a way to list all the self-signed certificate on the server, or maybe verify if a certificate for a port is a self-signed certificate or not?

Comment: Could you limit the scope to certificates that are in use on externally-visible ports? TCP ports, even? Otherwise, a self-signed certificate may exist in a file on the system, unused by anything.

Comment: Yes I want just the certificates in use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All certificates is difficult, since technically, every piece of server software could have its own certificates in non-standard locations. If you know the port you're interested in, run something along the lines of

```
openssl s_client -connect your.host.example:443 -showcerts
```

and look at the certificate chain. Your usual self-signed certificate would probably have a chain length of 1, on account of being self-signed.

Comment: Self-signed certificates will also have the same `Subject` and `Issuer`, which will be easier to test.

Comment: Before LetsEncrypt I used to run self-signed certificates on a number of internal systems. I had my own CA and used that to issue signed certificates. Technically it's self-signed (as in, I signed my own certificates) but it would fail any of these suggested tests. IMO there is no easy answer to this question.